# Split a String and then assign the splits

Tags: powershell, foreach, enumeration

I have a text file, in the text file are two names, exactly like this.

> Tom Hardy
>
> Brad Pitt

I use this, to take the names from the file and split them.

```
$Names = gc C:\Temp\Name.txt

ForEach-Object {-Split $Names}
```

How do I then assign each first name to $FirstName and each last name to $LastName?

The idea behind this is that further down the line, for each $FirstName I will be creating a specific individual item with each name.

I understand that after I run the above, each section of the name is assigned to $_ so I can do the same thing with each section i.e

```
$Names = gc C:\Temp\Name.txt

$SplitNames = ForEach-Object {-Split $Names}

ForEach ($_ in $SplitNames) {Write-Host 'Name is' $_}
Name is Tom
Name is Hardy
Name is Brad
Name is Pitt
```

Hope this makes sense, please let me know if more clarification is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as @Paxz but with some explanation and suggestions:

```
$Names = @(
    'Brad Pitt',
    'Tom Hardy',
    'Daniel Craig Junior'
)

# the .ForEAch method is used as it's faster then piping data to Foreach-Object
$result = $Names.ForEach({
    # we use the second argument of -Split to indicate 
    # we're only interested in two values
    $tmpSplit = $_ -split ' ', 2

    # we then create an object that allows us to 
    # name things propertly so we can play with it later withoout hassle
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Input = $_
        FirstName = $tmpSplit[0]
        LastName = $tmpSplit[1]
    }
})

# here we show the result of all our objects created
$result

# enable verbose text to he displayed
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

$result.ForEach({
    # here we can easily address the object by its property names
    Write-Verbose "Input '$($_.Input)' FirstName '$($_.FirstName)' LastName '$($_.LastName)'"
})

# disable verbose messages, because we don't need this in production
$VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
```

Comment: Can you explain the need for the ( and ) before and after each { } and what the @ symbols are doing?

Comment: `@()` is an `array` or collection of objects. The hashtable `@{}` is used to create a single `[PSCustomObject]` with its properties coming from the hasthable. Hashtables are the fastest objects in PowerShell AFAIK.

Answer (score 6):

```
# Read the input file line by line with Get-Content and send each line
# to the ForEach-Object cmdlet, which sees each line as automatic variable
# $_
Get-Content C:\Temp\Name.txt | ForEach-Object {
  # Split the line into tokens by whitespace.
  # * $firstName receives the 1st token,
  # * $lastName the 2nd one (if there were more, $lastName would become an *array*)
  $firstName, $lastName = -split $_
  # Work with $firstName and $lastName
}
```

If you want to collect the name pairs for later use, consider wrapping them in custom objects, as in [DarkLite1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51709662/45375).

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `ForEach-Object { -Split $Names }`
>
> `ForEach ($_ in $SplitNames) {Write-Host 'Name is' $_}`

If you call `ForEach-Object` without providing pipeline input to it, the script block is executed *once*, so that `ForEach-Object { -Split $Names }` is effectively the same as just calling `-Split $Names`.

Generally, these statements suggest that there's confusion around the distinction between PowerShell's various enumeration constructs.

---

#### PowerShell's various *enumeration constructs*:

- The **[`ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)**:

  - is designed to receive **input via the *pipeline*** (`|`)
  - reflects each input object in **automatic variable `$_`**
  - e.g., `1, 2, 3 | ForEach-Object { "number: $_ " }`
  - Note: Sending `$null` as input *does* result in an invocation - unlike in a `foreach` *loop*.
- The **[`foreach` *loop statement*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach)**:

  - is designed to **enumerate *a specified in-memory collection***
  - via a **self-chosen iteration variable** (better not to choose `$_`, to avoid confusion)
  - e.g., `foreach ($num in 1, 2, 3) { "number: $num" }`
  - Note: `$null` as the input collection does *not* result in entering the loop body - unlike with `ForEach-Object`.
- **PSv4+** also offers the **[`.ForEach()` array *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#methods-of-arrays)**:

  - Similar to the `foreach` loop, it is designed to **enumerate *an in-memory collection***, but you **[invoke it as a *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_methods) on the collection itself.**
  - Similar to the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet, it is **automatic variable `$_`** that reflects the current iteration's object.
  - It **offers additional functionality**, such as enumerating properties by name, performing type conversions, calling methods.
  - e.g., `(1, 2, 3).ForEach({ "number: $_" }`
  - Note: `$null` as the input collection does *not* result in an invocation of the script block - unlike with `ForEach-Object`.
- Perhaps surprisingly, PowerShell's **[`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) too performs enumeration** on inputs that happen to be collections.

  - The `switch` equivalent of `foreach ($num in 1, 2, 3) { "number: $num" }` is (note the use of automatic variable `$_` as the implicit iterator variable):
    `switch (1, 2, 3) { default { "number: $_"; continue } }`
  - `switch` is similar to the `foreach` loop statement in terms of memory efficiency, performance and output timing, so it won't be discussed separately below. Its advantage is the ability to use sophisticated conditionals as well as being able to enumerate the lines of a file directly, with the `-File` option.
  - Note: `$null` as the input collection *does* result in an evaluation of the branches - unlike with `foreach` loops.

**Somewhat confusingly, `foreach` is also a built-in *alias* for `ForEach-Object`.** If you use `foreach`, it is the parsing context that determines which construct is used: in a pipeline (command context, argument mode), `foreach` refers to the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet, otherwise it refers to the `foreach` *loop* (expression mode) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60043437/45375) for details.

---

#### Tradeoffs: What construct to use when:

Note: The following focuses on the loop-like constructs, but ***generally* applies** to **contrasting use of *cmdlets in the pipeline* (streaming)** on the one hand, vs. ***language statements* and *operator-based expressions / method calls*** on the other.<sup>[1]</sup>

- **performance** (execution speed)

  - the `foreach` loop is generally fastest, followed by the `.ForEach()` method, with the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet being the slowest (the pipeline is slow in general; see bottom section)
- **memory efficiency**

  - only the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet (the pipeline) offers *streaming* processing, where each object is processed as it is being produced; unless the overall result is collected in memory (as opposed to outputting to a file, for instance), this *keeps memory use constant*, irrespective of how many objects are ultimately processed.
  - `foreach` and `.ForEach()` require the input collection to be present in memory *in full*.
- **output timing**

  - the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet (and the pipeline in general) passes objects on as they're being processed / produced, so you usually start to see output right away.
  - `foreach` and `.ForEach()`, when directly operating on a command, must collect that command's output in full, up front, before enumeration can start.
- **syntactic convenience** and **feature set**

  - the `.ForEach()` method can be used *as-is* as part of an expression, whereas use of `ForEach-Object` requires enclosing `(...)` and use of a `foreach` loop requires enclosing `$(...)`
  - the `.ForEach()` method offers additional functionality that allows for concise expressions (emulating the functionality with `foreach` and `ForEach-Object` is possible, but more verbose)

---

#### Performance comparison:

Running the following **performance-comparison commands**, which employ a trivial loop body, shows `foreach` to be faster than `.ForEach()` in my tests, with `ForEach-Object` slowest, as expected. Note that the code downloads and defines the `Time-Command` function from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27) (I can assure you that doing so is safe, but you should always check the source code yourself):

```sh
# Download and define the Time-Command function.
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27/raw/Time-Command.ps1 | iex

Write-Verbose -vb "1,000 items, average of 10 runs"
$a=1..1000; Time-Command -Count 10 { foreach($e in $a) { (++$e) } }, { $a.ForEach({ (++$_) }) }, { $a | ForEach-Object { (++$_) } } | Out-Host

Write-Verbose -vb "100,000 items, average of 10 runs"
$a=1..1e5; Time-Command -Count 10 { foreach($e in $a) { (++$e) } }, { $a.ForEach({ (++$_) }) }, { $a | ForEach-Object { (++$_) } } | Out-Host
```

Results from a dual-core Windows 10 VM, with Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 7.2.0-preview.6; note that the absolute numbers are not important and will vary based on many variables, but the *ratio* (column `Factor`) should give you a sense.

**Windows PowerShell v5.1:**

```
VERBOSE: 1,000 items, average of 10 runs

Factor Secs (10-run avg.) Command                        TimeSpan
------ ------------------ -------                        --------
1.00   0.001              foreach($e in $a) { (++$e) }   00:00:00.0013639
3.99   0.005              $a.ForEach({ (++$_) })         00:00:00.0054464
7.46   0.010              $a | ForEach-Object { (++$_) } 00:00:00.0101785


VERBOSE: 100,000 items, average of 10 runs

Factor Secs (10-run avg.) Command                        TimeSpan
------ ------------------ -------                        --------
1.00   0.014              foreach($e in $a) { (++$e) }   00:00:00.0144434
37.56  0.542              $a.ForEach({ (++$_) })         00:00:00.5424872
62.61  0.904              $a | ForEach-Object { (++$_) } 00:00:00.9043278
```

---

**PowerShell Core 7.2.0-preview.6:**

```
VERBOSE: 1,000 items, average of 10 runs

Factor Secs (10-run avg.) Command                        TimeSpan
------ ------------------ -------                        --------
1.00   0.001              foreach($e in $a) { (++$e) }   00:00:00.0013071
4.23   0.006              $a.ForEach({ (++$_) })         00:00:00.0055324
8.04   0.011              $a | ForEach-Object { (++$_) } 00:00:00.0105058

VERBOSE: 100,000 items, average of 10 runs

Factor Secs (10-run avg.) Command                        TimeSpan
------ ------------------ -------                        --------
1.00   0.010              foreach($e in $a) { (++$e) }   00:00:00.0095252
34.12  0.325              $a.ForEach({ (++$_) })         00:00:00.3250133
57.83  0.551              $a | ForEach-Object { (++$_) } 00:00:00.5508560
```

---

<sup>Note: The above benchmarks have been updated after a flaw in the original methodology was discovered. The new numbers lead to different conclusions.</sup>

General observations:

- **`foreach` is by far the fastest, followed by `.ForEach()`, with `ForEach-Object` being slowest by far**

  - Note: While this as expected, given that the pipeline introduces overhead, the slowdown is in no small part owed to the ***inefficient implementation* of the `ForEach-Object` (and `Where-Object`) cmdlet as of PowerShell 7.2** - see [this blog post](https://powershell.one/tricks/performance/pipeline) for an excellent analysis, which led to [GitHub feature request #10982](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10982).
- **The performance advantage of `foreach` grows with the number of iterations, and it is considerable with large numbers**. Independently of the number of iterations, however, **`.ForEach()` appears to be about twice as fast as `ForEach-Object`**.
- In terms of absolute timings, PowerShell Core appears to perform better than Windows PowerShell with large iteration counts.
- On macOS (results not shown above), the slowdown factors seem to be larger, and execution seems to be slower in absolute terms too.
- Re-running the tests in the same PowerShell session widens the performance gaps, suggesting that only the `foreach` statement benefits from on-demand compilation.

---

<sup>[1] E.g., contrasting reading a file with *cmdlet* [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) vs. with *language statement* [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) `-File`; or contrasting filtering a collection with *cmdlet* [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) vs. via *method* [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) or *operator* [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

`Split` gives you an array with content after each posititon it splits.
You can address each entry in the array then for further purpose:

e.g.: `("Tom Hardy" -split " ")[0]` = `Tom`

```
$Names = gc C:\Temp\Name.txt

foreach ($name in $Names)
{
  $cutted = $name.Split()
  $firstname = $cutted[0]
  $lastname = $cutted[1]
  #Do whatever you need to do with the names here
}
```

---

As mentioned by @iRon, you can actually skip one step and directly save it from the split to the two variables:

```
$Names = gc C:\Temp\Name.txt

foreach ($name in $Names)
{
  $firstname, $lastname = $name -split " "
  #Do whatever you need to do with the names here
}
```

Or as a oneliner:

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\Name.txt" | % {$firstname, $lastname = $_ -split " "; #Do something with the variables}
```