# Is ForEach really an alias of ForEach-Object (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, foreach, alias

`ForEach` is documented as an alias of `ForEach-Object`. When I use `Get-Alias ForEach` it tells that it is in alias of `ForEach-Object`.

But,

- `ForEach-Object` Accepts parameters such as Begin Process and End, where `ForEach` doesn't accept them.

  - When we call `ForEach-Object` without any thing it prompts for parameter Process, and on calling `ForEach` it leaves a nested prompt with `>>`.
  - `%` and `ForEach` behave same, but `ForEach-Object` don't.

Here my questions are:

- Is `ForEach` really an alias of `ForEach-Object`?
- Which is better, `ForEach` or `ForEach-Object`?

Please share your thoughts.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are **two distinct underlying constructs**:

- The [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet*

  - This cmdlet has a built-in *alias* name: `foreach`, which just so happens to match the name of the distinct `foreach` *statement* (see next point).
- The [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) *loop statement* (akin to the lesser used `for` statement).

**What `foreach` refers to depends on the *parsing context*** - see [`about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing):

- In *argument mode* (in the context of a *command*), `foreach` is `ForEach-Object`'s alias.
- In *expression mode* (more strictly: *statement* mode in this case), `foreach` is the `foreach` *loop statement*.

---

As a **cmdlet**, **`ForEach-Object`** operates on ***pipeline input***.

- Use it process output from other commands in a *streaming* manner, *object by object*, as these objects are being received, **via the [*automatic `$_` variable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_)**.

As a **language statement**, the **`foreach` loop operates on *variables and expressions*** (which may include output collected from commands).

- Use it to process already-collected-in-memory results efficiently, **via a *self-chosen iterator variable*** (e.g., `$num` in `foreach ($num in 1..3) { ... }`); *doing so is noticeably faster* than processing via `ForEach-Object`.<sup>[1]</sup>
- Note that you cannot send outputs from a `foreach` statement directly to the pipeline, because PowerShell's grammar doesn't permit it; for streaming output to the pipeline, wrap a `foreach` statement in `& { ... }`. (By contrast, simple *expressions* (e.g., `1..3`) *can* be sent directly to the pipeline).

For more information, a **performance comparison** and a discussion of the **tradeoffs** (memory use vs. performance), including the **`.ForEach()` array method**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51712352/45375).

---

<sup>[1] However, note that the main reason for this performance discrepancy as of PowerShell 7.2.x isn't the pipeline itself, but `ForEach-Object`'s *inefficient implementation* - see [GitHub issue #10982](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10982).</sup>