# CSV cleanup and splitting into multiple rows

Tags: powershell

I'm fairly new to Powershell, so any help is appreciated... I've spent all morning searching and experimenting, but I'm not getting anywhere.

The goal is to write a script that pulls a CSV file containing hostnames, make some modifications, and then write the results to a new CSV for upload to a web application. The CSV is simple, with only a single column titled "host". Sample:

```
host
------
pc3463
pc234235.domain.somewhere.com
pc24234.domain.somewhere.com : e-34235
pc6432 : e-99124
```

There are two transformations of the data that need to occur:

1. Trim garbage: Any row containing " : " needs to have everything after the first space discarded. Example: the third row becomes "pc24234.domain.somewhere.com", and the fourth row becomes "pc6432".
2. Then, any row ending in ".domain.somewhere.com" needs to be split into two rows: line two is examined, left as-is, then a new line containing "pc234235" is created; line three is examined, left as-is, and a new line containing "pc24234" is created. The end result for each is two rows... one with host.domain.somewhere.com, and another with just host.

I know I'm missing something obvious, or misunderstanding how to go about this. What I'm hoping is if someone can show me an example of how to trim out the garbage in the first step, I can work the rest out on my own, but I'm not going to say no to help on step 2 also!

I've tried too many variations to list here, but here are the two most common errors I'm seeing:

```
Import-Csv $csvfile
ForEach ($line in $csvfile){$clean = $line.Substring(0, $s.indexOf(' '))}
```

OR

```
ForEach ($line in Import-Csv $csv_file){$line.Substring(0, $s.indexOf(' '))}
```

Result in:

```
Error: "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"
```

I also tried:

```
Import-Csv $csvfile
ForEach-Object ($line in $csvfile){$clean = $line.Substring(0, $s.indexOf(' '))}
```

Result:

```
Error: "Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement."
Error: "Missing closing ')' in expression."
```

Comment: The "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" error is probably from `$s.IndexOf(...)` - `$s` isn't defined anywhere. Perhaps you meant to write `$line.IndexOf(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

This part strikes me as wrong:

````
``` Import-Csv $csvfile
ForEach-Object ($line in $csvfile){
````

And the second error-message "Unexpected token 'in' in expression“ seems to confirm it. I would have done this instead before any manipulation of the data happens:

```
 $P = Import-Csv -Path .\Processes.csv;

#you can then access the data by using the property name / column name
foreach($item in $P){
$hostNameRaw= $item.host}
# and run some operation on it
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) to parse your CSV data into *objects*, and process them one by one using [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), with the help of the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split):

```bash
Import-Csv $csvfile |
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.host -match ' ') {  # contains space
      $_.host = (-split $_.host)[0] # Keep only the part before the first space.
    }
    # Try to split the .host property value into a hostname and domain part.
    $hostName, $domain = $_.host -split '\.', 2
    if ($domain) { # A domain name is present.
      # Output an extra object with the hostname alone.
      [pscustomobject] @{ host = $hostName }
    }
    # Output the original, potentially cleaned-up object.
    $_
  } # | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 -LiteralPath out.csv
```

Note the use of the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) inside the [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ … }`) passed to `ForEach-Object`, which refers to the pipeline input object at hand.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `ForEach ($line in $csvfile){$clean = $line.Substring(0, $s.indexOf(' '))}`

As Mathias points out, `$s` isn't defined in your code, and you probably meant to use `$line` instead.
An *undefined* variable in PowerShell defaults to `$null`, and any attempt to call a *method* on a `$null` value causes the error you saw.

> `ForEach-Object ($line in $csvfile){$clean = $line.Substring(0, $s.indexOf(' '))}`

- Your syntax isn't valid for use with the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet*.
- You're confusing it with the [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) *language statement*.

  - Somewhat confusingly, the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet* can *also* be referred to as `foreach`, via an *alias*.
  - It is the *syntactic context* that determines whether `foreach` refers to the *language statement* - which requires a `($iteratorVariable in …)` clause before its `{ … }` body - or the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet* - which receives its input *from the pipeline* and only ever uses the automatic `$_` variable as the implicit analog to an iterator variable.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60043437/45375) for more information.