# How do you store a list of users (C:\Users) in PowerShell to use later on in the same script?

Tags: powershell

I am having issues trying to figure out how to make this script work.  I need to get a list (either stored in powershell somehow or saved to a text file) of users from the C:\Users folder and then run a script deleting certain cache data in each of those users folders.  Because I am running this based off of a list that I pulled from AD (into another .txt file), I am having trouble understanding how to run it based off of a foreach, foreach concept where there are two foreach statements in one script.

```
$Computers = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Cache Cleanup Project\June 10 Lists\ComputerUp.txt" | foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
dir \\$Computer\C$\Users | select Name | Out-File "C:\temp cache cleanup project\Computer Users\$Computer.txt"
```

I feel like I am missing something in the script above.  What I need is a folder filled with .txt files with the name of each computer name that is in the ComputerUp.txt file.  In each file will be a list of users for that specific machine.  My other scripts will need to reference each of these files in order to go through and clear out the cache'd files.

I hope this makes sense.  I have to clean up caches on near 700 machines and each user profile has to be scrubbed and this was the best way I could figure out how to do it.  If anyone has any better suggestions, I am all ears.

Comment: Regarding the confusion between the `foreach` _statement_ vs. the `ForEach-Object` _cmdlet_ (somewhat confusingly, the latter has an _alias_ also named `foreach`: in addition to Santiago's answer, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60043437/45375).

Comment: @mklement0 sir, do you happen to know what could happen to the excellent article by Dave Wyatt about performance tests filtering collections (the original link was [here](https://powershell.org/2013/11/powershell-performance-filtering-collections/)). I would recommend that article for anyone new to PowerShell.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, I found an archived copy in the Wayback machine (it is slow to load): https://learn-powershell.net/2015/02/20/a-look-at-filtering-performance-in-powershell/ I also came across this: https://learn-powershell.net/2015/02/20/a-look-at-filtering-performance-in-powershell/

Comment: @mklement0 I was looking at this one, sadly, it's not the original post from Dave. Even Don Jones was on that discussion, it's sad to see that article gone forever :(

Comment: My bad, @SantiagoSquarzon, I accidentally pasted the same link twice: here's the archived copy of the Dave Wyatt article, via the [Wayback Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback%20Machine): https://web.archive.org/web/20200923025608/https://powershell.org/2013/11/powershell-performance-filtering-collections/

Comment: My pleasure, @SantiagoSquarzon; re _enumeration_ benchmarks (`foreach` statement vs. `.ForEach()` method vs. `ForEach-Object` cmdlet): I've just revised the benchmarks in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51712352/45375) and was surprised to see how much slower the `.ForEach()` method is than a `foreach` statement; if you're up for it, I'd be interested in hearing if you get similar results.

Comment: @mklement0 excellent answer on that post! I love performance tests, I already knew a bit about pros and cons on the different loops in PS, probably why I usually tend to use classic approaches on my answers. That article from Dave has always been my rule of thumb since the moment I read it, and it's also awesome because he talks about the `PowerShell filter`, something that not many people talk about.

Comment: Thanks, @SantiagoSquarzon; interesting to see that functions in the pipeline perform better than `.ForEach()`. Note that `filter` is just a simplified form of a function (syntactic sugar), with the following equivalence: `filter foo { $_ }` is the same as `function foo { process { $_ } }`

Answer (score 2):

> What I need is a folder filled with .txt files with the name of each computer name that is in the ComputerUp.txt file

Using the file system for this is unnecessary - you can store this information in a variable in-memory instead:

```
# Read the list of computers from disk
$Computers = Get-Content .\path\to\ComputerUp.txt

# Create a dictionary to hold ComputerName->ListOfUsers data
$UsersPerComputer = [ordered]@{}

foreach($computer in $Computers){
  # enumerate the remote folder names
  $listOfNames = Get-ChildItem \\$Computer\C$\Users |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

  # assign the list to the dictionary, use the computer name as the key
  $UsersPerComputer[$computer] = $listOfNames
}
```

Now you can retrieve the list for a single computer by name:

```
$targetMachine = 'Computer123'

$UsersPerComputer[$targetMachine] # this will resolve to the list of user folder names we got from Computer123
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're confusing [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.1) with [`ForeEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1).

- With `foreach` your script would look like this:

```
$Computers = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Cache Cleanup Project\June 10 Lists\ComputerUp.txt"

foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    (Get-ChildItem "\\$Computer\C$\Users").Name |
    Out-File "C:\temp cache cleanup project\Computer Users\$Computer.txt"
}
```

- With `ForEach-Object` it would look like this:

```
Get-Content "C:\Temp\Cache Cleanup Project\June 10 Lists\ComputerUp.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-ChildItem "\\$_\C$\Users").Name |
    Out-File "C:\temp cache cleanup project\Computer Users\$_.txt"
}
```

---

As a side note, doing this should get the job done exponentially faster:

```
$Computers = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Cache Cleanup Project\June 10 Lists\ComputerUp.txt"

$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem C:\Users
}

$result | Group-Object PSComputerName | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group.Name | Out-File "C:\temp cache cleanup project\Computer Users\$($_.Name).txt"
}
```

Comment: Here is what I ended up :


`$Computers = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Cache Cleanup Project\ComputerUp.txt"

$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem C:\Users
}

$result | Group-Object PSComputerName | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group.Name | Out-File "C:\temp\cache cleanup project\Computer Users\$($_.Name).txt"
}`

Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: @MjrPayne Check if there are no empty / white spaces or empty lines in your input file.

Comment: Checked and no spaces exist where they shouldnt be.  Changed the Get-ChildItem path to "\\$Computers\c$\users" but still got the same error.

Comment: I did check the results folder for the 'foreach' option and it did yield results.  However, all it did was list the computer name as the .txt file name and nothing in the file.  

It does yield an error when running, "Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path '\\\C$\Users' because it does not exist"  Not sure why this is happening.  Ill post the script as I ran it in another comment due to space restrictions.

Comment: `$Computers = Get-Content "C:\Temp\CacheCleanUp\ComputerUp.txt"
foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    (Get-ChildItem "\\$Computer\C$\Users").Name |
    Out-File "C:\Temp\CacheCleanUp\Computer Users\$Computer.txt"
}`

Comment: @MjrPayne Seems like the file you're pointing to `C:\Temp\CacheCleanUp\ComputerUp.txt` doesn't have computers in it. Check if the `$computers` variable has the computers in it. This is basic troubleshooting.

Comment: It does have computers in it.  

It is formatted as such:
`
computername                TestConnection
------------                       --------------
JBLMW12K3AWK024        True
`

Will that make a difference?

Comment: @MjrPayne yes it will. Your file should only contain the hostnames and nothing else.