# How to remove a lines if a line contains empty value after = symbol using powershell or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, powershell

How to remove a lines if a line contains  empty value after = symbol using powershell or Javascript?

My input value is

```
variable1 = value1
variable2 = value2
variable3 =
variable4 = value4
variable5 =
```

the values may change .i am looking for a script that remove lines if the value is empty after = symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to alter an .INI file and by doing so, you may in fact ruin some applications initialization..

Having said that, in PowerShell you can do:

1. when loading from a text file

```
$result = Get-Content -Path 'X:\theInputFile.txt' | Where-Object { $_ -match '^\w+\s*=\s*\S+' }
```

2. when parsing a multiline string

```
$string = @'
variable1 = value1
variable2 = value2
variable3 =
variable4 = value4
variable5 = 
'@ 

$result = $string -split '\r?\n' | Where-Object { $_ -match '^\w+\s*=\s*\S+' }
```

Variable `$result` will be an array of strings:

```
variable1 = value1
variable2 = value2
variable4 = value4
```

You can save that back to (a new) file using

```
$result | Set-Content -Path 'X:\theNewInputFile.txt'
```

Regex details:

```
^          Assert position at the beginning of the string
\w         Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
   +       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\s         Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
=          Match the character “=” literally
\s         Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\S         Match a single character that is a “non-whitespace character”
   +       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Comment: You can even remove the `Where-Object` as `-match` acts as a filter when applied to an array: `$result = ($string -split '\r?\n') -match '^\w+\s*=\s*\S+'`

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69963335/45375), which uses a *streaming, cmdlet-based* approach, with a (pure) *operator* approach, which is faster, but more memory-intensive (memory use is typically not a concern with text files):

As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out, comparison operators such as [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) act as *filters* if the LHS operand (input) is an *array*, so you can match a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) directly against an array of lines in order to get the sub-array of matching lines:

```sh
# Filter the lines of file inputFile.txt by returning only those on which
# "=" is followed by at least one non-whitespace character ("\S"), 
# optionally preceded by any number of other characters (".*").
@(Get-Content inputFile.txt) -match '=.*\S'
```

<sup>You can speed up the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) call by adding `-ReadCount 0`.</sup>

As for when to use a streaming vs. a pure operator approach: see the section about tradeoffs in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51712352/45375).